# Intero Emacs error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, intero

I am getting the following error. Anyone knows how to solve it?[image]

Comment: It might have to do with what you have in your `stack.yaml`, like the `resolver` entry for example

Comment: According to the error message, you seem to be using a nightly snapshot of GHC from ten days ago (8.0.1.20161117) rather than e.g. the latest stable version (8.0.1). Is that expected?

Comment: (By the way: please don't post code or error messages as images. Paste them as text instead.)

Comment: Basically the same issue issue can arise [with hoogle](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2524). [This is the proposed fix](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2643).